# Superposition of traveling waves/ pulses?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For some PDE, say an one dimensional reaction diffusion equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$
a traveling wave is a solution only depending on the single variable $\xi:=x-ct$ for some $c\neq 0$.

Now, I am wondering, if a superposition of traveling waves

(1) with different speeds, say 
$$
u_N=\sum_{j=1}^N u(x-c_j t)
$$

(2) or same speed but shifted, say
$$
u_N=\sum_{j=1}^N u(x-ct-L_j)
$$

are again traveling waves (or maybe quasi-traveling N-waves, whatever this may mean but I have heard this name)?

And how do they look like, f.e. how do N-pulses look like? Pulses are traveling wave that converge to some equilibrium, i.e.$\lim_{xi\to\pm\infty}u(\xi)\to u_{*}$.

Comment: Superposition only works for linear problems.

Comment: So, in non-linear problems like here, what would happen in (1) or (2)?

Comment: You don't have superposition at all for non-linear problems, so $u_{N}$ can't be written as as sum of $u_{j}$. The wave speed for a particular solution depends on the PDE i.e [Fishers equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_equation) requires $c > 2$, but the $1$-soliton solution to the [KDV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg–de_Vries_equation) just requires $c > 0$ to ensure the wave is right (or left) travelling. Also, the wave can be translated some distance $x_{0}$ ($x_{0}$ constant) and remain a solution.

Comment: That is, if we map $x - ct \mapsto x - ct + x_{0}$, then $f^{*} = f(x - ct + x_{0})$ is also a solution to the problem.

Comment: Ok! My original aim was to express that we have some solution having different "humps", say at positions $x_1,...,x_N$ and then this humps move for example up to each other and may annhilitate, say something like: We have $u_{N+2}$ for $t\in [0,T_1)$ and then, for $t\in [T_1,T_2)$, we have $u_N$, i.e. two "humps" annihilated. What is a better way to express this?

Comment: I think you might be looking for multi-soliton solutions to various PDEs. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton) for some information on solitons, then google 'multi-soliton solutions' to a particular PDE of your choice.